# Handling server timeout (503) for request with heavy calculations

Tags: django

I deployed my first project in which I'm visualising clusters in a user's Spotify playlist, using Django for backend and React for frontend. One of the services of my Django backend receives an array of features of the tracks in the selected playlist. These features are then reduced using [Scikit Learn's TSNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html). However, it may take more than 30 seconds before the service returns a response with output to visualise, meaning that the server times out with code 503. I'm looking for suggestions to solve this issue and any would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I think there are two solutions, one is preferred so you can use Celery for example to do background task. The other solution is just adding some configurations to your reverse proxy, are you using Nginx ?

Comment: Cool, I’ll look into that. I’m only using gunicorn at the moment, not nginx.

Comment: Try adding this **--timeout 120** to your gunicorn runserver command